# How to search for strings within nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested

One of the questions for an assignment I'm doing consists of looking within a nested lists consisting of "an ultrashort story and its author.", to find a string that was inputted by a user. Not to sure on how to go about this, here is the assignment brief below if anyone would like more [clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHVz0.png). There are also more questions I'm not to sure on eg "find all stories by a certain author". Some explanations, or point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated :)

```
list = []
mylist = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

string = input("String?")

if string in [elem for sublist in mylist for elem in sublist] == True:
    list.append(elem)
```

This is just an example of something i've tried, the list above is similar enough to the one i'm actually using for the question. I've just currently been going through different methods of iterating over a nested lists and adding mathcing items to another list. above code is just one example of an attemp i've made at this proccess.

Comment: Could you give is a brief example data structure? What have you tried so far - do you have any example code that shows where you've gotten stuck?

Comment: We aren't doing your homework for you, at least show us you did something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
""" the image above states that the data is in the
form of an list of sublists, with each sublist containing
two strings
"""

stories = [
    ['story string 1', 'author string 1'],
    ['story string 2', 'author string 2']
]


""" find stories that contain a given string
"""
stories_with_substring = []
substring = 'some string'  # search string

for story, author in stories:
    # if the substring is not in the story, a ValueError is raised
    try:
        story.index(substring)
        stories_with_substring.append((story, author))
    except ValueError:
        continue

""" find stories by a given author
"""
stories_by_author = []
target_author = 'first last'

for story, author in stories:
    if author == target_author:
        stories_by_author.append((story, author))
```

This line here

```
for story, author in stories:
```

'Unpacks' the array. It's equivalent to

```
for pair in stories:
    story = pair[0]
    author = pair[1]
```

Or to go even further:

```
i = 0
while i < len(stories):
    pair = stories[i]
    story = pair[0]
    author = pair[1]
```

I'm sure you can see how useful this is when dealing with lists that contain lists/tuples.

You may need to call `.lower()` on some of the strings if you want the search to be case insensitive

Comment: Can you add some explanation about what you're doing and why? Op is looking to learn about how to do this, rather than simply having the code written for them

Comment: This makes sense to me, however I'm having some issues when trying to print the lists of append stories, when I print stories_with_substring it looks like this: [('Corpse parts missing. Doctor buys yacht.', 'Margaret Atwood')]
[('Corpse parts missing. Doctor buys yacht.', 'Margaret Atwood'), ('Starlet sex scandal. Giant squid involved.', 'Margaret Atwood')] sorry also new to stack overflow to not sure on how to post things very well

Comment: Are you just calling `print(stories_with_substring)`? That won't work. You need to loop over the list in the same way they were constructed and print each element individually

Comment: That seemed to work well, I will test out a little more thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things here. Your example showed the use of a list comprehension, so let's focus on some other aspects of this problem.

**Recursion**

You can define a function that iterates through all the items in the top level list. Assuming you know for sure all items are either strings or more lists, you can use `type()` to check if each item is another list, or is a string. If it's a string, do your search - if it's a list, have your function call itself. Let's look at an example. Please note that we should never using variables named `list` or `string` - these are core value types and we don't want to accidentally overwrite them!

```
mylist = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

def find_nested_items(my_list, my_input):
    results = []
    for i in mylist:
        if type(i) == list:
            items = find_nested_items(i, my_input)
            results += items
        elif my_input in i:
            results.append(i)
    return results
```

We're doing a few things here:

1. Creating an empty list named `results`
2. Iterating through the top level items of `my_list`
3. If one of those items is another list, we have our function call itself - at some point this will trigger the condition where an item is *not* a list, and will eventually return the results from that. For now, we assume the results we're getting back are going to be correct, so we concatenate those results to our top level `results` list
4. If the item is not a list, we simply check for the existence of our input and if so, add it to our results list

This kind of recursion is typically very safe, because it's inherently limited by our data structure. It can't run forever unless the data structure itself is infinitely deep.

**Generators**

Next, let's look at a much cooler function of python 3: generators. Right now, we're doing all the work of collecting the results in one go. If we later on want to iterate through those results, we need to iterate over them separately.

Instead of doing that, we can define a generator. This works **almost** the same, practically speaking, but instead of collecting the results in one loop and then using them in a second, we can collect and use each result all within a single loop. A generator "yields" a value, then stops until it is called the next time. Let's modify our example to make it a generator:

```
mylist = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

def find_nested_items(my_list, my_input):
    for i in mylist:
        if type(i) == list:
            yield from find_nested_items(i, my_input)
        elif my_input in i:
            yield i
```

You'll notice this version is a fair bit shorter. There's no need to hold items in a temporary list - each item is "yielded", which means it's passed directly to the caller to use immediately, and the caller will stop our generator until it needs the next value.

`yield from` basically does the same recursion, it simply sets up a generator within a generator to return those nested items back up the chain to the caller.

These are some good techniques to try - please give them a go!

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try these methods and let you know how if they worked for me

Comment: Hi dave I was wondering if you had any tips on how to display the stories and movies like "short story....."  then underneather slightly idenented "--author" rather then just     for x in stories_with_substring: print x which just prints it like a list, cheers